# System.Net.WebException on YoutubeExtractor when downloading a video

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, download, youtube

## Environment

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- C#
- WPF application

## Issue

- YoutubeExtractor throws System.Net.WebException when downloading a video.

I got YoutubeExtractor by Nuget and it doesn't work. The VideoInfo object isn't null. I tried several videos on Youtube and the same exceptions popped up. I googled the issue and it didn't give me much help.

Here's the code.

```
var videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1wLtAXDgqg");
VideoInfo video = videos
    .First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);

if (video.RequiresDecryption)
    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);

var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, System.IO.Path.Combine("D:", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));

videoDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender_, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.ProgressPercentage);

videoDownloader.Execute(); // I got the exception here.
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT : 2017/10/26 13:42 GMT**

Alexey 'Tyrrrz' Golub's answer helped so much! I corrected his original code and here it is.

```
using YoutubeExplode;
using YoutubeExplode.Models.MediaStreams;

var client = new YoutubeClient();
var video = await client.GetVideoAsync("bHzHlSLhtmM");
// double equal signs after s.VideoQuality instead of one
var streamInfo = video.MuxedStreamInfos.First(s => s.Container == Container.Mp4 && s.VideoQuality == VideoQuality.Medium360);
// "D:\\" instead of "D:"
var pathWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\\", video.Title);
// streamInfo.Container.GetFileExtension() instead of video.VideoExtension (video doesn't have the property)
var path = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(pathWithoutExtension, streamInfo.Container.GetFileExtension());
// new Progress<double>() instead of new Progress()
await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(streamInfo, path, new Progress<double>(d => Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("p2"))));
```